# Animation by Bezier points

Tags: animation, svg

I need a lot of different paths to animate a slideshow pictures. Animation will be made on the points defined by the Bezier curve. But I did not find any gallery or examples of this paths.
The second way is to convert SVG paths in points, but how it can be implemented?
Are there any ready-made galleries for animation along the path?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a starting point. This is copied directly from [the Mozilla Developer Network site for the SVG animateMotion function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateMotion).

```html
<svg width="120" height="120"  viewBox="0 0 120 120"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >

    <!-- Draw the outline of the motion path in grey, along
         with 2 small circles at key points -->
    <path d="M10,110 A120,120 -45 0,1 110 10 A120,120 -45 0,1 10,110"
          stroke="lightgrey" stroke-width="2" 
          fill="none" id="theMotionPath"/>
    <circle cx="10" cy="110" r="3" fill="lightgrey"  />
    <circle cx="110" cy="10" r="3" fill="lightgrey"  />

    <!-- Here is a red circle which will be moved along the motion path. -->
    <circle cx="" cy="" r="5" fill="red">

        <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
        <animateMotion dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite">
           <mpath xlink:href="#theMotionPath"/>
        </animateMotion>
    </circle>
</svg>
```